# path to node edit page

Tags: nodes, uri

I am using js injector to add script to my drupal website. But the script is also loading on the admin pages and node edit pages.

I have selected the option

Add tracking to specific pages  Every page except the listed pages

and defined admin/* which removes the script from admin pages but what path should I define to exclude the script from the node edit pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the path match for *node/[nid]/edit* pages, you can use

**node/*/edit**

as the page match string there.

Comment: I'd prefer node/*/* to also exclude node/3234/delete and all tabs provided by modules, like revisions, moderation et cetera.